# Example Needed For One To Many in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables call products and combo.
products table will have all the products data's like sn,product name, product price, product image...etc

and combo table is to group the products like
first product's id
second product's id
third product's id   will be in a one group called Set 1

i need to get the combo products details using one to many in mysql.

how it can be done

Thank in advanced

Comment: Most people would use a `SELECT` query, unless you're talking about creating the tables in the first place, in which case it would be `CREATE`.

Comment: Does your combo table have multiple columns for each product? If so, you need to change that to one product per row instead.

Comment: Put a **clear** example of what you want to achieve (es. with some sample data, the schema of your tables etc). You may want to link a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) page to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lookup table pattern:

You can try designing the schema so that each product => combo pair is one row.

For example:

```
product_id, combo_id
product_1, combo_1
product_2, combo_1
product_3, combo_1
product_1, combo_2
```

When you do a select from the tables, you'll want to use some very good joining and grouping:

`"select product.product_name, combo.combo_id from combo, product where product.product_id = combo.combo_id and combo_id = 'combo_1'";`

Anyway, read up on methods to do lookup tables. This is just my suggestion of how you might want to design the schema.